# Calculation of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!\cdot e^{n}}{n^n\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: limits

> Calculation of limit $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!\cdot e^{n}}{n^n\sqrt{n}}$

Plan Stirling approximation $$n!\approx \bigg(\frac{n}{e}\bigg)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$$ for large $n$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^n}{e^n}\cdot \sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{2\pi}$$

How would I evaluate the limit without Stirling's approximation?

Comment: I don't see any other way to get a handle on $n!$, why do you want to do that?

Comment: I would go one step further: this limit being $\sqrt{2\pi}$ is **immediately equivalent** to Stirling's approximation. Maybe you should be looking for proofs of Stirling's approximation?